# Shortcut for running Spyder specifies non-existent folder

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda, spyder

Just now (Oct/2023), I installed Anaconda anew on Windows 10 in
order to install Python 3.9, Pyspark, and Spyder.  The Conda
environment is "py39".  I just did this on another laptop in Aug/2023,
so I was familiar with what I had to do.  Basically, I copied the
"Spyder (py39)" shortcut so that I could point it to my own CMD script
that sets up the PySpark environment variables.

I found that things changed quite a bit between August and October.
For one thing, the user-specific Anaconda home changed from
`%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3` to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\anaconda3`.
That's easy to handle; I just pointed a `CONDA_HOME` variable to the
new loccation from a CMD command line:

```
> setx CONDA_HOME "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\anaconda3"
```

I named the copied "Spyder (py39)" shortcut as "SpyderSpark (py39)"
and set the Target field to my own `SpyderSpark.cmd` script:

```
set "HADOOP_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1"
set "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=Python"
set "PYSPARK_PYTHON=Python"

REM The following are from querying environment variables from
REM the Python REPL after launching pyspark from Conda prompt
set "JAVA_HOME=%CONDA_HOME%\envs\py39\Library"
set "SPARK_HOME=%CONDA_HOME%\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark"

REM The following was in the Target field of the original
REM "Spyder (py39)" shortcut from the Aug/2023 installation
start ""^
 "%CONDA_HOME%\pythonw.exe"^
 "%CONDA_HOME%\cwp.py"^
 "%CONDA_HOME%\envs\py39"^
 "%CONDA_HOME%\envs\py39\pythonw.exe"^
 "%CONDA_HOME%\envs\py39\Scripts\spyder-script.py"
```

The baffling thing is that in the "Spyder (py39)" shortcut of the new
Oct/2023 installation, the Target fields ends with the following
instead of the last physical line immediately above.

```
 "%CONDA_HOME%\env"
```

This is in place of:

```
 "%CONDA_HOME%\envs\py39\Scripts\spyder-script.py"
```

The path `%CONDA_HOME%\env` doesn't correspond to any existing file or
folder.  Since there is nothing in the Target field that refers to
Spyder, I would have expected the "Spyder (py39)" shortcut to pop up
an error when executed, but it doesn't.  It launches the Spyder GUI
just fine.

Since I'm using the above `start` command in my `SpyderSpark.cmd`, I'd
really like to know ***why the newer Oct/2023 `start` command specifies a
non-existent path, doesn't make any reference to Spyder at all, but
still launches Spyder without an error.  Thanks for any light that can
be shed on this.***

**P.S.** The `SpyderSpark.cmd` script above, with the reference to
`spyder-script.py`, launches Spyder, but I'm troubleshooting the
inability to instantiate a SparkSession object.  I consider that to be
a separate issue.  The answer to this posted question may help.

Answer (score 0):

The *partial* answer is that the Target field of a shortcut is limited to 260 characters.  It doesn't look like I'm pushing that limit in my posted question, but that's because I've abbreviated the paths using `%CONDA_HOME%`

I refer to this as a *partial* answer because it still leaves some questions.  For example, if I explicitly use the final physical line `"%CONDA_HOME%\env"` in my `SpyderSpark.cmd` script, it doesn't work.  I need the full `"%CONDA_HOME%\envs\py39\Scripts\spyder-script.py"`.

As well, if look at the Target field of shortcut `Spyder` [*not* `Spyder (py39)`], the final physical line ends in `%CONDA_HOME%\Scripts\spyder-script.p`, which is missing the "y" in the extension "py".  The file's basename is a lot closer to the full `spyder-script.py` and it just *happens* to be 259 characters long.  The missing "y" is the 260th character, which is the field limit.  It is probably present but inaccessible.

Same with the shortcut `Spyder (py39)`, whose Target field ends on the 259th character with `%CONDA_HOME%\env`.  The rest of the path must be present because the shortcuts works, but the rest of the path is probably inaccessible due to limitations of the shortcut GUI panel.

Googling indicates that the length limit is imposed by the shortcut properties dialogue box, and the shortcut itself can have a longer Target.